# Rails, Turbolinks and spinner

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am trying to replace a text link with a spinner on click. I have this:

```
$(document).on('page:fetch', function(e) {
  $('.spinner').replaceWith( "<img src='<%= asset_path('layout/spinner.gif') %>'>" );
});
```

But it is obvious that all links with the .spinner class gets the spinner. I want to replace only on the *clicked* link and only IF it has the spinner class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: When the link is clicked you want it to be replaced by a spinner?

Comment: Yes! The clicked link (the one that triggered the page:fetch).

Comment: And those links are inside the section of the page that is fetched?

Comment: No - they are on the page where the link is:

1. Click the link
2. Replace link text with spinner
3. Fetch the new page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have some code which gets triggered on both 'page:load' and ready events so that they work for full page loads and Turbolinks page loads. The code below will add a 'data-click' attribute with value of true on the '.spinner' that was clicked.

```
#inside both the ready and 'page:load' events
$('.spinner').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('data-clicked', true);
});
```

The code below will look for the '.spinner' with a data-clicked attribute with value of true and apply the spinner image on it.

```
$(document).on('page:fetch', function(e) {
  $('.spinner[data-clicked="true"]').replaceWith( "<img src='<%= asset_path('layout/spinner.gif') %>'>" );
});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't, I'm afraid. Nothing happens. I think that the contents of the click event handler doesn't get fired. Execution of JS on the page stops before it can be executed.

Comment: @jriff just updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: YES! That did it (but you should change "data-click" to "data-clicked" in the top code fragment).

Comment: Can you tell me why this works when my approach doesn't? I don't really see why there is a significant difference.

Comment: I get it now - this is a way to get the link that was clicked without using the event object (which doesn't have any information about the trigger for the event...)

Comment: I edited my typo on 'data-clicked'. And yes, that's spot on. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - it really helped a lot. Enjoy the bounty :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the on click event to change the links with the `spinner` class so that when they are clicked, they turn into the spinner:

```
$('.spinner').on("click", function() {
  $(this).replaceWith( "<img src='<%= asset_path('layout/spinner.gif') %>'>" );
});
```

Then, only the ones that are clicked will be changed.

Comment: That won't work I'm afraid. I tried it (incredibly enough the exact same code that you came up with). The next page gets loaded before the content is replaced. I think that Turbolinks is doing something behind the scenes. The code I pasted in my question works - the spinner is shown before the page changes. But that affects all of the links which wasn't the intent.